# Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{1200} \to U(-1/2,1/2)$. Find $P\{S>20\}$ and $P\{|S| > 20\}.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

**Exercise :**

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{1200}$ be independent and uniformly distributed in the 
>   interval $(-1/2,1/2)$.
>
> If : $S=X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_{1200}$, estimate the probabilities $P\{S>20\}$ and $P\{|S| > 20\}$.

Sorry for not providing an attempt but I'm at a loss on how to start here. I would really appreciate a thorough explanation.

All I can say is that we can observe that :

$$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{1200} \to U(-1/2,1/2)$$

which means that :

$$f_{X_1}(x_1)=f_{X_2}(x_2)=\dots=f_{X_{1200}}(x_{1200})= 1$$

Please, assist me with this problem as it's an exam question that I am trying to grasp for tomorrow's semester exams.

Comment: $S$ follows the [uniform sum distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).

Comment: Hint: By the Central Limit Theorem, $S$ has an approximately Normal distribution.  You will need to compute its mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Second hint: By a symmetry argument you also have $$P(S > 20) = P(S < -20)$$

Comment: Well, I guess $E[X_i] = 0$ and $V[X_i] = 1/12$ since the distribution is uniform. I can proceed with CLT then, which I was missing as a clue, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Central limit theorem:

$$ S_{1200} =\sum^{1200}_{i=1}X_i \sim N(n\mu,n\sigma^2) $$

here $S_{1200} \sim N(0, 100)$

Comment: Verified the answ. (+1) In this notation $\sigma^2 = 100,\, \sigma = 10.$ In R statistical software `1 - pnorm(20, 0, 10)` returns 0.02275013, so $P(S>20)\approx 0.02275.$ and, by symmetry about $0,\,$  $P(|S|>20)$ is twice that. // $S$ is very close to normal; even for $n=12$ (vs 1200) the approx is quite good.